# can we configure precomm it hook for particular branch/tag

Tags: svn, hook, commit, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

Scenario  : i have precommit hook configured in my svn repo of multiple projects.I have blocked commits in code which include synchronize method or println method,But in some cases i want to give grant so that coders can commit those methods .

Now thing is that i have multiple projects, if i comment out my portion of lock in precommit hook then it will raise a risk as other project coders can commit prohibited methods at same time.

Please guide me how can i configure my precommit hook as per particular branch if its possible.

Removing svn rights using access file is very difficult at times as no of users are large.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for path based authorization? Following link may be useful 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html 
And I'd also recommend if you visit and see if you are looking at the same objective as that of 
[SVN Python pre-commit hook - how to find out target branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986400/svn-python-pre-commit-hook-how-to-find-out-target-branch)

Comment: Thanks :) path based authorization is already there.But no of users are large so its difficult to remove rights .

Comment: in short, i want to remove my hook script for a particular branch whenever needed for any number of users who have rights in auth file ,but others branch will be working with hook with no issue.

Comment: I am still searching for solution. .. Anyone knows if we can apply precommit hook branch by branch to control some code measures.?

Answer (score 0):

Use `svnlook` subcommands in your hooks

Read `svnlook help dirs-changed` in order to get (wiil be) changed in transactions paths in repo

Read `svnlook help author` if you want to implement additional user-level checks in hook